# How do I get components in my header fit great together

Tags: html, css

I am trying do design a header with a search form and navigation menu. But the components do not quite fit nicely together, the symmetry of the design is wrong.

[image]

For example look at Quora great header in firebug, everything looks great and it has a great symmerty for is components:
[image]

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
  <body>
      <header id="layout_header">
        <div id="header_contents">
            <nav class="nav_list">
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Profil", '#' %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign out", '#' %></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <form class="form_wrapper">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" required>
            </form>
        </div>
      </header>
        <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
/* The layout of the header*/
#layout_header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll; 
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom-color: #E5E5E5;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background-image: none;
  min-height: 31px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin:0;
}
/* Header content */
#header_contents{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 870px;
}

/* Navigation */
.nav_list{
    float: right;
}
.nav_list ul{
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav_list ul li{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    float: left;
}
.nav_list ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #222222;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_list ul li a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* search form*/
.form_wrapper{
    width: 485px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.form_wrapper #search{
    width: 463px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.form-wrapper #search::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.form-wrapper #search:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;

}

.form-wrapper #search:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**My Q:**

- How do I fix it so every component fits together great?
- Is the problem in the form_wrapper?

Comment: What do you think of Stack Exchange's header, then? :)

Comment: The stack exchange´s header looks great to, the symmerty is great looking to =)

Comment: Your searh field seems a little bit long... May be it can be a little bit smaler ... and most of the search area on website are place on the right side.

Comment: I am buildning something that requir that width, and I know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to replicate what you were trying to imply. Have a look.
This is the main html body:

```
<header id="layout_header">
    <div id="header_contents">
        <nav class="nav_list">
            <form class="form_wrapper">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" required>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Signout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

And this is the corresponding CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#layout_header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-bottom-color: #E5E5E5;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background-image: none;
    /*   min-height: 31px; */

    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Header content */

#header_contents {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 90%;
}
/* Navigation */
/* .nav_list{
    float: right;
} */

.nav_list ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0
}
.nav_list ul li {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.nav_list ul li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #222222;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_list ul li a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* search form*/

.form_wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.form_wrapper #search {
    width: 463px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.form-wrapper #search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.form-wrapper #search:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.form-wrapper #search:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```